# Install and configure dolibarr process for AWS?

Tags: command-line, apache-httpd, webserver, aws, lynx

Getting to [know](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/404116/17056) AWS -- it's interesting.  Running 16.04 xenial on AWS and looking to install [dolibarr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolibarr).  On 17.10, where I have a GUI, dolibarr installs fine.

*Few questions about running web servers/apps on AWS.  (AFAIK apache web server is used to serve pages.)*

The install process, at least on Ubuntu 17.10, involves navigating to `localhost/dolibarr` to complete the configuration.  How would this be accomplished?  Navigate to the Elastic IP (EIP) as `xxx.xxx.xxx/dolibarr`?  That seems unlikely and not a very secure way to configure.

Perhaps use lynx from the CLI to navigate to `localhost/dolibarr`?

Once configured, just browse to the EIP from any outside client?

Answer (score 1):

lynx kinda sorta worked for configuring dolibarr on `aws`.  I got a login page at the end of the day.  However, I don't recall being prompted for some details, like the administrator login.  Unfortunately, it hung and displayed `SQL` -- I think a command to create a table.  Eventually I just opened a new `ssh` connection and used `lynx` to navigate, again, to `localhost/dolibarr` where I was prompted to login.  Success?

see also:

[locked out of LAMP application (dolibarr) -- reset credentials from database?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/404155/17056)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best (and probably simplest) solution is to start an [ssh port forwarding tunnel](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example), listening on 127.0.0.1:80 of your client machine, but forwarding the http requests to 127.0.0.1:80 on your server machine. On this way, you will be able to access the 127.0.0.1:80 on the *server machine* by connecting 127.0.0.1:80 on your *client* (i.e. from any browser).

As you can see in the link, the command is

```
ssh -L 80:127.0.0.1:80 your.remote.machine.com
```